# Can google see the contents of an iframe when spidering?

Tags: iframe, indexing, seo, web-crawler

I've looked this up and have not found consistent answers. I want to embed a google doc in my page (when you publish your google doc it gives you an iframe). Will search engines like google be able to read the contents of the document (just text, but may have important keywords)? Or will it act as if the page was empty?

If it cannot index the text then is there any way to have the embed in some sort of server side include so that it appears to be hard-coded into the html to spiders?

Answer (score 0):

No, they will not read it and assosiate the content to your site. They will eventually crawl it sometime but it will not be associated as "your" content.

Only way to do it, is to write server side code that scrapes the content and outputs it inside your page.

Right now, the page looks empty to the search engines.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure that they can't since you can start seeing iframe content being rendered in the site previews under Google Search i.e. any facebook page tab application can be seen now and they all work through iframes